# position: absolute; bottom: 0; create a few pixels gap

Tags: html, css, sass

An exemple is better than words : http://jsfiddle.net/k8p3E/2/

HTML:

```
    <div class="captionImage">
        <a href="">
            <img src="">
            <p>voodoo</p>
        </a>
    </div>
```

SCSS:

```
.captionImage {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  a {
    color: white;
    img {
      border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: blue;
    }
    p {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0; /* voodoo */
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: rgba(65,53,40,0.9);
      text-align: center;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see p is starting at something like bottom: -5px and not 0.

I'm stuck on this problem since quite a time now and i'm asking for your help.

Thanks.

EDIT: i'm trying to align the paragraph on the bottom of the image with on 0.9 opacity, that's why i don't want it under the image.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/k8p3E/4/

You need to set `vertical-align` property (top, middle, whatever) to your `img`

Answer (score 1):

`display: block;` for the `img` should do the trick:
[**LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/k8p3E/3/)